# confusion about Hopcroft-Karp time complexity analysis

Tags: time-complexity, runtime-analysis, bipartite-matching

From Wikipedia:
"Each phase increases the length of the shortest augmenting path by **at least one**: the phase finds a maximal set of augmenting paths of the given length, so any remaining augmenting path must be longer. Therefore, once the initial ${\displaystyle {\sqrt {|V|}}}$ phases of the algorithm are complete, the shortest remaining augmenting path **has **at least ${\displaystyle {\sqrt {|V|}}}$edges in it".****

Well here my confusion arises. Since Augmenting paths have odd length, how can length of augmenting path be increased by one (results in path of even length -> not augmenting path)? Shouldn't it be **by at least two**? Then after ${\displaystyle {\sqrt {|V|}}}$ phases of the algorithm are complete, the shortest augmenting path **has at least ${\displaystyle {2\sqrt {|V|}}}$edges in it".** Am i missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right that each phase increases the length of the shortest augmenting path by at least two since that length is always odd. (It is always odd because an augmenting path alternates between unmatched edges and matched edges, starting and ending with unmatched edges.)

1. Each shortest augmenting path in the $1$st phrase contains at least $1$ edge.
2. Each shortest augmenting path in the $2$nd phrase contains at least $3$ edges.
3. And so on.
4. Each shortest augmenting path in the $k$th phrase contains at least $2k-1$ edges.

In particular, each shortest augmenting path in each phrase after $\lfloor\sqrt{|V|}\rfloor$ phrases will contain at least $2 \lfloor\sqrt{|V|\rfloor} + 1$ edges.

---

On the other hand, [that Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopcroft%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm#Analysis) is not wrong when it says "Each phase increases the length of the shortest augmenting path by **at least one**". Had it said "... by one", it would have been wrong.

Although the description "at least one" is not as strong as "at least two", it is good enough to help deduce the algorithm "takes a total time of $O(|E|\sqrt{|V|})$ in the worst case.".

Even with the strong version, "at least two", we can not lower that asymptotic complexity, although we could reduce the estimate for the hidden constant factor of that big $O$-notation.

Comment: That's what i thought explanation would be, it makes sense for the sake of complexity analysis. On the other hand "at least one" part left me wondering if I misunderstood something and was bothering me all day. Thank you.